# Invalid Procedure call and argument Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Got an error in the following code, debug shows the error is on:

```
Set Target = Union(Target, Range("B" & i))
```

---

```
Dim Length As Long
Dim a As String
Dim Target As Range

Length = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Target = Nothing

For i = 1 To Length
    a = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
    If a Like "*June 18, 2020" Then
        Set Target = Union(Target, Range("B" & i))
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `Target` is nothing then you cannot union nothing to a range.  You will need an if to start the range:

```
Dim Length As Long
Dim a As String
Dim Target As Range

Length = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Target = Nothing

For i = 1 To Length
    a = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
    If a Like "*June 18, 2020" Then
        If Target is nothing then
            Set Target = Sheet1.Range("B" & i)
        Else
            Set Target = Union(Target, Sheet1.Range("B" & i))
        End If
    End If
Next i
```